# Unable to insert data in Google Sheet vertically, one column and multiple rows in Android

Tags: android, spreadsheet, insert-update

I am new in using Google APIs, and I have created a Google Sheet using [this link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android).

Now I want  to insert data some data  in column A but any range which I am using it insert data in all column like if I am using range A:A than it should insert data in column A but my code is inserting in all column.

My code to insert data in Google Sheet is this:

```
 public List<String> insertdataApi_firstentry() throws IOException {
            Log.i(TAG, "insertdataApi1234 ");

            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            String spreadsheetId = newSpreadSheet.getSpreadsheetId().toString();;


String range = "A:A";




//            sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setBackground("red");
//            sheet.getRange("A3:C3").setBackground("red");
//            sheet.getRange("A10:C10").setBackground("red");
            ValueRange oRange = new ValueRange();
            Log.d(TAG, "insert value id" + spreadsheetId);


            List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();

                set_value.add("Host Name1");


     set_value.add("Host Name2");
 set_value.add("Host Name3");
 set_value.add("Host Name4");
 set_value.add("Host Name5");

            data.add(set_value);

            oRange.setValues(data);

            Log.d(TAG, "insert value" + oRange);
            Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Append request =
                    mService.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, range, oRange);
            request.setValueInputOption("RAW");
            Log.d(TAG, "insert value" + request);
            AppendValuesResponse response = request.execute();


            return results;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may find that if "please" is too much trouble to type, people will assume you've not made much of an effort to research your problem. Would you fix that in your post, please? You can take out all the "please help me" stuff anyway, since it sounds like begging.

Comment: ok...next time i will take care....

Comment: How about this time? The [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45299019/edit) is just here.